# javascript: delete reference to the running code

Tags: javascript, reference

I was just wondering if there is any risk when you execute code like this:

```
window.doSomething = function() {
   window.doSomething = null;

   // do some stuff here
}
```

Will this always run fine, or might there be a situation in which the garbage collector will clean it up while it's still running?

Comment: It's like you said, only the reference will be deleted. The garbage collector will not kill the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.doSomething = null ;
```

That will just remove the property `doSomething` from `window` which was previously referencing your function.

The function that you're currently in will run until the end, because entering the function increases the reference count, preventing it from being destroyed prematurely.

After the function is done, it will be scheduled for garbage collection.